# Capistrano 3 invoking task with role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

```
namespace :package do
  task :install, :packages do |task, args|
    on roles(:all) do
      execute :sudo, "apt-get install -y #{args[:packages]}"
    end
  end
end

namespace :git do
  task :install do
    # 1 code
    invoke 'package:install', 'git-core' # works but I want this installed only on the :app role
    # 2 code
    on role(:app) do
      invoke 'package:install', 'git-core' # errors
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I'm not running `#1` and `#2`, I am running either `#1` or `#2`.

Is there a way to `invoke` a task **and** specify which `role` it's executed on?

Comment: It looks like your problem may be in the fact that your install task is trying to do it on all roles... on roles(:all) but the method calling that task is already specifying only the app role